# Joomla 3 menu php in foreach find second li submenu

Tags: php, joomla, foreach

in Joomla menu module php - default.php,How can i find the second li submenu and add class name 'the-secondsubmenu' into it?

the output will looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav"> 
    <li>

            <a></a> 
            <ul>
                <li class="the-secondsubmenu">
                    <a></a>
                </li>
            </ul> 

    </li>
</ul>
```

**i'm add this line in foreach**

```
if($item->level < 2): $counter += count($item); endif;
```

**and add these**

```
if ($item->deeper)
{
    $class .= ' deeper';
}
elseif($item->deeper && $counter === 2){

    $class .= ' deeper the-secondsubmenu';
}
```

**THE PHP**

```
foreach ($list as $i => &$item)
{
    if($item->level < 2):
        $counter += count($item);
    endif;

    $class = 'item-' . $item->id;

    if (($item->id == $active_id) OR ($item->type == 'alias' AND $item->params->get('aliasoptions') == $active_id))
    {
        $class .= ' current';
    }

    if (in_array($item->id, $path))
    {
        $class .= ' active';
    }
    elseif ($item->type == 'alias')
    {
        $aliasToId = $item->params->get('aliasoptions');

        if (count($path) > 0 && $aliasToId == $path[count($path) - 1])
        {
            $class .= ' active';
        }
        elseif (in_array($aliasToId, $path))
        {
            $class .= ' alias-parent-active';
        }
    }

    if ($item->type == 'separator')
    {
        $class .= ' divider';
    }


    if ($item->deeper)
    {
        $class .= ' deeper';
    }
    elseif($item->deeper && $counter === 0){

        $class .= ' deeper the-secondsubmenu';
    }
```

these code not working,
As always, your assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

if you write this code, the second part won't be executed because the test includes the same test as the first block.

```
if ($item->deeper) {
    $class .= ' deeper';
}
elseif ($item->deeper && $counter === 2) {
    $class .= ' deeper the-secondsubmenu';
}
```

maybe you should try to put the second block first :

```
if ($item->deeper && $counter === 2) {
    $class .= ' deeper the-secondsubmenu';
}
elseif ($item->deeper) {
    $class .= ' deeper';
}
```